# How to change GWT-Visualization defualt locale?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I'm using Google visualization API in my GWT app, AnnotatedTimeLine to be more specific. It works fine, but I'd like the chart messages and zoom options to be localized (message saying there is no data etc). I have specified locale in my module's XML file, but this doesn't seem to work. Still getting english messages. Any ideas?

Regards,
Jerzy

Comment: Are you trying to use the browser Locale or are you trying to get it from a cookie / user selection? The server Locale obviously won't work.